# Periodic Groups of Matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices

Is there any example of a non-finite periodic group of matrices over a field? (I mean of course with regard to the product of matrices). Issai Schur proved that a periodic group of matrices over the field of complex number has a normal abelian subgroup of finite index, so when the field is $\mathbb{C}$ the example I look for must be non-finitely generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly if you allow any field, you can take an infinite field $K$ of prime characteristic $p$, and then consider
$$
\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & a\\0&1\end{bmatrix} : a \in K \right\} \cong (K, +),
$$
an abelian group of exponent $p$.

Over the complex numbers, you may simply take the $1 \times 1$ matrix group
$$
\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} a \end{bmatrix} : \text{there is $n \ge 1$ such that $a$ is a $p^n$-th root of unity} \right\},
$$
where $p$ is a prime.

Comment: Oh yeah right! While in the $\mathbb{C}$-field case?

Comment: @W4cc0, just added.